# Yii2 Swiftmailer can't connect to SMTP sometimes, returns Internal Server Error

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

Sometimes my program can send a message and sometimes not, according to one of my colleagues it is because of the connectivity here in our place. Sometimes I can't ping the SMTP address.

Now I tried retrying to send the message in a loop, yet it doesn't because the program will stop because of an internal server error.

```
  $mail_params = $params['mail'];
  $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($mail_params['smtp'], $mail_params['port'], $mail_params['encryption'])
  ->setUsername($mail_params['user'])
  ->setPassword($mail_params['password']);

  $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
  $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
               ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['notificationEmail'] => 'TMC Scheduler'])
               ->setTo([$to])
               ->setBody(trim($email_message));

             while ($i = 0) {
                $i = $mailer->send($message);
             }

             return $i
```

I've been stuck here 4 days. Do you guys have any ideas? I'm running out of it.